# React native expo av - Manipulating Video Images?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, video-processing, expo-av

I really struggle to find documentation on how to manipulate video images with `expo av`.

I manage to do this easily in a classic web app by copying video image to a canvas while playing. Something similar to:

```js
ctx.drawImage(myVideo, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);
```

I can then manipulate the image, like transforming pixels or apply feature detection algorithms on the image, which is very useful.

I am simply looking to do this in expo, or as an alternative in pure react native.

Thanks for your lights!